# PHP JSON Decoding To Array To Grab Specific Key Values (All fields same name)

Tags: php, arrays, json, zoho

I am pulling JSON data from an API URL. The problem: Under FL there are duplicate KEYS: "val" and "content". I only need to pull specific KEYS.

Please excuse me if my formatting is not correct to SO standards.*

My question is posted below the json and code.

### JSON FROM URL

```
{
    "response": {
        "result": {
            "Leads": {
                "row": [
                    {
                        "no": "1",
                        "FL": [
                            {
                                "val": "LEADID",
                                "content": "123"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "SMOWNERID",
                                "content": "3232"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Lead Owner",
                                "content": "Cassie"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "First Name",
                                "content": "Bobby"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Last Name",
                                "content": "Something"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Email",
                                "content": "email@gmail.com"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Mobile",
                                "content": "1111111111"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "SMCREATORID",
                                "content": "0000003213"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Created By",
                                "content": "Cassie"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Created Time",
                                "content": "2019-04-03 15:14:05"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Modified Time",
                                "content": "2019-04-03 17:13:58"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Full Name",
                                "content": "Bobby Something"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Street",
                                "content": "123 Fake Rd"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "City",
                                "content": "Fakecity"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "State",
                                "content": "FK"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Zip Code",
                                "content": "11111"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Email Opt Out",
                                "content": "false"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Salutation",
                                "content": "Mr."
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Last Activity Time",
                                "content": "2019-04-03 17:13:58"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Tag",
                                "content": "Tag"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Account Name",
                                "content": "Something"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Territory Manager",
                                "content": "Michael Something"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Territory Manager_ID",
                                "content": "321237000000291111"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Classification",
                                "content": "Something"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Area",
                                "content": "Zone 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "val": "Account Number",
                                "content": "32345"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "uri": "/crm/private/json/Leads/getRecords"
    }
}
```

### PHP CODE

```
$url = 'URL';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed = json_decode($data, true);

$eachEntry = $parsed['response']['result']['Leads']['row'];

foreach ($eachEntry as $entry) {

    $FL = $entry['no'];

    //printf('%s'.PHP_EOL, $FL);
    printf("\n");

    $entries = $entry['FL'];

    foreach ($entries as $value) {

        $val = $value['val'];

        $content = $value['content'];

        $out = $val." ".$content;

        printf('%s'.PHP_EOL, $out);
        printf("\n");
    } 

}
```

### RESULTS

```
LEADID 123

SMOWNERID 3232

Lead Owner Cassie

First Name Bobby

Last Name Something

Email email@gmail.com

Mobile 1111111111

SMCREATORID 0000003213

Created By Cassie

Created Time 2019-04-03 15:14:05

Modified Time 2019-04-03 17:13:58

Full Name Bobby Something

Street 123 Fake Rd

City Fakecity

State FK

Zip Code 11111

Email Opt Out false

Salutation Mr.

Last Activity Time 2019-04-03 17:13:58

Tag Tag

Account Name Something

Territory Manager Michael Something

Territory Manager_ID 321237000000291111

Classification Something

Area Zone 1

Account Number 32345
```

### QUESTION

How can I pull only the fields I have listed below in the example? And do not pull every field.

### EXAMPLE

```
"val": "First Name",
"content": "Bobby"

,

"val": "Last Name",
"content": "Something"

,

"val": "Street",
"content": "123 Fake Rd"

,

"val": "City",
"content": "Fakecity"

,

"val": "State",
"content": "FK"

,

"val": "Zip Code",
"content": "11111"
```

### EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
First Name Bobby

Last Name Bobby

Street 123 Fake Rd

City Fakecity

State FK

Zip Code 11111
```

### Set JSON from URL into HTML Table

[PHP JSON To Array Values Into HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55523177/php-json-to-array-values-into-html-table)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the code to do what you describe. Simply don't print them if they're not in the list of fields you want.

```
$valuesIWant = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Street", "City", "State", "Zip Code"];

foreach ($eachEntry as $entry) {

    $FL = $entry['no'];

    //printf('%s'.PHP_EOL, $FL);
    printf("\n");

    $entries = $entry['FL'];

    foreach ($entries as $value) {

        $val = $value['val'];

        $content = $value['content'];

        if (in_array($val, $valuesIWant)) {
            $out = $val." ".$content;

            printf('%s'.PHP_EOL, $out);
            printf("\n");
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: It really was that simple :) - Marked as answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you just need to maintain an array where you can provide all the options you want to fetch and check that in the loop like in the example below.

```
$url = 'URL';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed = json_decode($data, true);

$eachEntry = $parsed['response']['result']['Leads']['row'];

$required = ['First Name','Last Name','Street','City','State','Zip Code'];

foreach ($eachEntry as $entry) {

    $FL = $entry['no'];

    //printf('%s'.PHP_EOL, $FL);
    printf("\n");

    $entries = $entry['FL'];

    foreach ($entries as $value) {

        if(!in_array($value['val'],$required))
            continue;

        $val = $value['val'];

        $content = $value['content'];

        $out = $val." ".$content;

        printf('%s'.PHP_EOL, $out);
        printf("\n");
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mapArray = {
  "lastName": "Last Name cannot be null!",
  "email": "Email cannot be null!",
  "firstName": "First Name cannot be null!"
};

$.map(mapArray, function(val, key) {
  alert("Value is :" + val);
  alert("key is :" + key);
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oops, looks like you got the wrong tech. JS vs. PHP requested.