# PHP JSON To Array Values Into HTML Table

Tags: php, json, html-table

I am pulling JSON data from an API URL. I need to pull specific KEYS and put them into a table with columns and rows. 6 (col) x 20+ (rows). The KEYS are all duplicate (val, content) of each other:

### JSON EXAMPLE

```
    {
        "response": {
            "result": {
                "Leads": {
                    "row": [
                        {
                            "no": "1",
                            "FL": [
                                {
                                    "val": "LEADID",
                                    "content": "123"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "SMOWNERID",
                                    "content": "3232"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Lead Owner",
                                    "content": "Cassie"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "First Name",
                                    "content": "Bobby"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Last Name",
                                    "content": "Something"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Email",
                                    "content": "email@gmail.com"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Mobile",
                                    "content": "1111111111"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "SMCREATORID",
                                    "content": "0000003213"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Created By",
                                    "content": "Cassie"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Created Time",
                                    "content": "2019-04-03 15:14:05"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Modified Time",
                                    "content": "2019-04-03 17:13:58"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Full Name",
                                    "content": "Bobby Something"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Street",
                                    "content": "123 Fake Rd"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "City",
                                    "content": "Fakecity"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "State",
                                    "content": "FK"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Zip Code",
                                    "content": "11111"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Email Opt Out",
                                    "content": "false"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Salutation",
                                    "content": "Mr."
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Last Activity Time",
                                    "content": "2019-04-03 17:13:58"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Tag",
                                    "content": "Tag"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Account Name",
                                    "content": "Something"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Territory Manager",
                                    "content": "Michael Something"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Territory Manager_ID",
                                    "content": "321237000000291111"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Classification",
                                    "content": "Something"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Area",
                                    "content": "Zone 1"
                                },
                                {
                                    "val": "Account Number",
                                    "content": "32345"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "uri": "/crm/private/json/Leads/getRecords"
        }
    }
```

### PHP CODE

```
<?php

$url = 'URL';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed = json_decode($data, true);

$eachEntry = $parsed['response']['result']['Leads']['row'];

$valuesIWant = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Street", "City", "State", "Zip Code"];

echo '<table class="uabb-table-inner-wrap">';
 echo   '<thead class="uabb-table-header"><tr class="table-header-tr">
            <th class="table-header-th">First Name</th><th class="table-header-th">Last Name</th><th class="table-header-th">Street</th><th class="table-header-th">City</th><th>State</th><th class="table-header-th">Zip Code</th>
        </tr></thead>';
foreach ($eachEntry as $entry) {

    $FL = $entry['no'];

    //printf("\n");

    $entries = $entry['FL'];



    echo '<tbody class="uabb-table-features"><tr class="tbody-row">';
    foreach ($entries as $value) {

        $val = $value['val'];

        $content = $value['content'];

        if (in_array($val, $valuesIWant)) {

            //$out = $val;
           $out2 = $content;

            //echo '<td>'. $out .'</td>';
            echo '<td class="table-body-td">'. $out2 .'</td>';

        }

    }
    echo '</tr></tbody>';
}

echo '</table>';

?>
```

I am trying to output into a table structure:

### TABLE OUTPUT EXAMPLE

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvVp0.jpg

---

This Is An Extension Question From: [PHP JSON Decoding To Array To Grab Specific Key Values (All fields same name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55520394/php-json-decoding-to-array-to-grab-specific-key-values-all-fields-same-name)

### SOLUTION

```
<style>
.uabb-table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    zoom: 1;
    display: flex;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-element-box {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.uabb-table-inner-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

.fl-module-uabb-table .uabb-table-wrapper .uabb-table-inner-wrap {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
}


.uabb-table .uabb-table-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.fl-module-uabb-table .uabb-table-wrapper .uabb-table-inner-wrap {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
}

.uabb-table-inner-wrap .uabb-table-header .table-header-th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 15px;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-th {
    overflow-wrap: normal;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-th, .uabb-table .uabb-table-features .table-body-td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-tr .table-header-th .th-style .head-inner-text, .uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-tr .table-header-th .th-style {
    background: none;
}

.uabb-table .table-header-th .th-style {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-tr .table-header-th .th-style .head-inner-text, .uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-tr .table-header-th .th-style {
    background: none;
}

.content-text {text-transform: uppercase;}

</style>

<?php

$url = 'URL';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed = json_decode($data, true);

$eachEntry = $parsed['response']['result']['Leads']['row'];

$valuesIWant = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Street", "City", "State", "Zip Code"];

echo    '<div class="uabb-table-module-content uabb-table">
            <div class="uabb-table-element-box">
                <div class="uabb-table-wrapper">
                    <table class="uabb-table-inner-wrap">
                        <thead class="uabb-table-header">
                            <tr class="table-header-tr">
                                <th class="table-heading-0 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-0 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">First Name</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-1 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-1 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">Last Name</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-2 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-2 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">Street</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-3 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-3 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">City</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-4 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-4 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">State</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-5 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-5 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">Zip Code</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>';
foreach ($eachEntry as $entry) {

    $FL = $entry['no'];

    //printf("\n");

    $entries = $entry['FL'];

    echo '<tbody class="uabb-table-features"><tr class="tbody-row">';
    foreach ($entries as $value) {

        $val = $value['val'];

        $content = $value['content'];

        if (in_array($val, $valuesIWant)) {

            //$out = $val;
           $out2 = $content;

            //echo '<td>'. $out .'</td>';
            echo '<td class="table-body-td  table-body-0" colspan="" rowspan=""><span class="content-text">'. $out2 .'</span></td>';

        }

    }
    echo '</tr></tbody>';
}

echo '</table></div></div></div>';

?>
```

### Next Step Is To Make This Table Editable And Post Update To CRM API.

[PHP JSON Array Values In HTML Table Post Update To API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55540388/php-json-array-values-in-html-table-post-update-to-api)

Comment: What you've posted, as-is, is _not_ valid JSON.  Also, "it is not working for me" is not really a helpful problem statement.  What _is_ happening?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: Maybe I can, but I won't.  If it doesn't exist in the body this question, then most people won't look at it.

Comment: I updated the body with the full JSON. Thanks Patrick!

Comment: Great!  How about my other questions?

Comment: where is the PHP that you mentioned using that echo's the table?

Comment: Move the header row right below the opening table tag and get rid of the printf and I think you'll be there.  [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/35354c50b2960f3f0f45295d6305c189ce9f85a6)

Comment: Thanks Patrick - I posted the full solution.

Comment: Next Step is to make the table editable - then update through the api.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this:

```
<style>
.uabb-table {
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    zoom: 1;
    display: flex;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-element-box {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.uabb-table-inner-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}

.fl-module-uabb-table .uabb-table-wrapper .uabb-table-inner-wrap {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
}


.uabb-table .uabb-table-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.fl-module-uabb-table .uabb-table-wrapper .uabb-table-inner-wrap {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0;
}

.uabb-table-inner-wrap .uabb-table-header .table-header-th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 15px;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-th {
    overflow-wrap: normal;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-th, .uabb-table .uabb-table-features .table-body-td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-tr .table-header-th .th-style .head-inner-text, .uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-tr .table-header-th .th-style {
    background: none;
}

.uabb-table .table-header-th .th-style {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-tr .table-header-th .th-style .head-inner-text, .uabb-table .uabb-table-header .table-header-tr .table-header-th .th-style {
    background: none;
}

.content-text {text-transform: uppercase;}

</style>

<?php

$url = 'URL';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$parsed = json_decode($data, true);

$eachEntry = $parsed['response']['result']['Leads']['row'];

$valuesIWant = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Street", "City", "State", "Zip Code"];

echo    '<div class="uabb-table-module-content uabb-table">
            <div class="uabb-table-element-box">
                <div class="uabb-table-wrapper">
                    <table class="uabb-table-inner-wrap">
                        <thead class="uabb-table-header">
                            <tr class="table-header-tr">
                                <th class="table-heading-0 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-0 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">First Name</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-1 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-1 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">Last Name</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-2 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-2 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">Street</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-3 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-3 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">City</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-4 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-4 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">State</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                                <th class="table-heading-5 table-header-th" rowspan="" colspan="">
                                    <label class="head-style-5 th-style">
                                        <label class="head-inner-text">Zip Code</label>
                                    </label>
                                </th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead>';
foreach ($eachEntry as $entry) {

    $FL = $entry['no'];

    //printf("\n");

    $entries = $entry['FL'];

    echo '<tbody class="uabb-table-features"><tr class="tbody-row">';
    foreach ($entries as $value) {

        $val = $value['val'];

        $content = $value['content'];

        if (in_array($val, $valuesIWant)) {

            //$out = $val;
           $out2 = $content;

            //echo '<td>'. $out .'</td>';
            echo '<td class="table-body-td  table-body-0" colspan="" rowspan=""><span class="content-text">'. $out2 .'</span></td>';

        }

    }
    echo '</tr></tbody>';
}

echo '</table></div></div></div>';

?>
```